# Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter, Caused by class IgniteSpiException Failed to deserialize object with given class loader sun.misc.Launcher

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, ignite, gridgain

```
I am using "gridgain-community-8.8.1" package to bring up ignite in one AWS EC2 instance and access that from AWS EMR Spark-3.0.1 job. While trying to get the ignite instance from spark job using "Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConf)", its throwing exceptions. I am using same java openJDK8 and gridgain library 8.8.1 for both EC2 instance and EMR spark job.

Below ignite config I have used to bring up ignite in EC2 instance, ignite was successfully brought up: (using ./gridgain-community-8.8.1/bin/ignite.sh aws-s3-ip-finder.xml)
```

aws-s3-ip-finder.xml content is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <!-- Enable peer class loading. -->
        <!-- <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/> -->
        <!-- Set deployment mode. -->
        <!-- <property name="deploymentMode" value="CONTINUOUS"/> -->

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.s3.TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder">
                        <property name="awsCredentialsProvider" ref="aws.creds"/>
                        <property name="bucketName" value="a206768-la-ignite-s3-ip-finder"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Instance Profile based credentials -->
    <bean id="aws.creds" class="com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider">
        <constructor-arg value="false" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Below is my scala codes to connect to this EC2 ignite instance:

```
def connectToIgniteClient(): Ignite = {
    logInfo(">>> Connecting to ignite-client")
    
    val instanceProfileCreds = new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false)
    logInfo(">>> IP finding")

    val ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder()
    ipFinder.setAwsCredentialsProvider(instanceProfileCreds)
    ipFinder.setBucketName("a206768-la-ignite-s3-ip-finder")
    logInfo(">>> S3 connected")

    val discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi()
    discoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder)
    logInfo(">>> Spi connected")

    val igniteConf = new IgniteConfiguration()
    igniteConf.setClientMode(true)
    igniteConf.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi)
    logInfo(">>> Config set")

    Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConf) //Exception is thrown from this line
  }
```

Below are the exception logs from EMR spark cluster:

```
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO Client: Application report for application_1616693342082_0001 (state: RUNNING)
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 10.150.80.195
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1616693536055
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-10-150-81-252.xxxx.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:20888/proxy/application_1616693342082_0001/
     user: hadoop
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1616693342082_0001 has started running.
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 45257.
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on ip-10-150-81-252.xxxx.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:45257
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, ip-10-150-81-252.xxxx.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com, 45257, None)
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-10-150-81-252.xxxx.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:45257 with 1028.8 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, ip-10-150-81-252.xxxx.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com, 45257, None)
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, ip-10-150-81-252.xxxx.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com, 45257, None)
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO BlockManager: external shuffle service port = 7337
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, ip-10-150-81-252.xxxx.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com, 45257, None)
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /metrics/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@194224ca{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
21/03/25 17:32:24 INFO SingleEventLogFileWriter: Logging events to hdfs:/var/log/spark/apps/application_1616693342082_0001.inprogress
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO Utils: Using initial executors = 50, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
21/03/25 17:32:25 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://YarnAM)
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO IgniteCommunicatorPerson: >>> Spark initialized
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO IgniteCommunicatorPerson: >>> Loading Person data to ignite caches
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO IgniteCommunicatorPerson: >>> Connecting to ignite
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO IgniteCommunicatorPerson: >>> Connecting to ignite-client
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO IgniteCommunicatorPerson: >>> IP finding
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO IgniteCommunicatorPerson: >>> S3 connected
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO IgniteCommunicatorPerson: >>> Spi connected
21/03/25 17:32:25 INFO IgniteCommunicatorPerson: >>> Config set
21/03/25 17:32:25 WARN : Failed to resolve default logging config file: config/java.util.logging.properties
Console logging handler is not configured.
21/03/25 17:32:25 WARN G: Ignite work directory is not provided, automatically resolved to: /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-FV02OVOM7RT4/ignite/work
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: 

21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: Config URL: n/a
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=null, pubPoolSize=8, svcPoolSize=8, callbackPoolSize=8, stripedPoolSize=8, sysPoolSize=8, mgmtPoolSize=4, dataStreamerPoolSize=8, utilityCachePoolSize=8, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=8, buildIdxPoolSize=1, igniteHome=null, igniteWorkDir=/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-FV02OVOM7RT4/ignite/work, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@4d1f1ff5, nodeId=c2f73ab1-066c-4fc1-b1d2-2ebd6ca79311, marsh=BinaryMarshaller [], marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, p2pEnabled=false, netTimeout=5000, netCompressionLevel=1, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=0, ackTimeout=0, marsh=null, reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectGateway@23f8036d, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@68f69ca3[Count = 1], stopping=false, clientPool=null, nioSrvWrapper=null, stateProvider=null, connectionRequestor=null], evtSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi@1e3566e, colSpi=NoopCollisionSpi [], deploySpi=LocalDeploymentSpi [], indexingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.indexing.noop.NoopIndexingSpi@2842c098, addrRslvr=null, encryptionSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.encryption.noop.NoopEncryptionSpi@2820b369, tracingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.tracing.NoopTracingSpi@46b21632, clientMode=true, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=1, rebalanceTimeout=10000, rebalanceBatchesPrefetchCnt=2, rebalanceThrottle=0, rebalanceBatchSize=524288, txCfg=TransactionConfiguration [txSerEnabled=false, dfltIsolation=REPEATABLE_READ, dfltConcurrency=PESSIMISTIC, dfltTxTimeout=0, txTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange=0, deadlockTimeout=10000, pessimisticTxLogSize=0, pessimisticTxLogLinger=10000, tmLookupClsName=null, txManagerFactory=null, useJtaSync=false], cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=10000, sysWorkerBlockedTimeout=120000, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=30000, metricsLogFreq=60000, connectorCfg=ConnectorConfiguration [jettyPath=null, host=null, port=11211, noDelay=true, directBuf=false, sndBufSize=32768, rcvBufSize=32768, idleQryCurTimeout=600000, idleQryCurCheckFreq=60000, sndQueueLimit=0, selectorCnt=4, idleTimeout=7000, sslEnabled=false, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, sslFactory=null, portRange=100, threadPoolSize=8, msgInterceptor=null], odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=1, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=null, binaryCfg=null, memCfg=null, pstCfg=null, dsCfg=null, activeOnStart=null, autoActivation=null, clusterStateOnStart=null, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=0, sockRcvBufSize=0, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=8, selectorCnt=4, idleTimeout=0, handshakeTimeout=10000, jdbcEnabled=true, odbcEnabled=true, thinCliEnabled=true, sslEnabled=false, useIgniteSslCtxFactory=true, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, thinCliCfg=ThinClientConfiguration [maxActiveTxPerConn=100, maxActiveComputeTasksPerConn=0]], mvccVacuumThreadCnt=2, mvccVacuumFreq=5000, authEnabled=false, failureHnd=null, commFailureRslvr=null, sqlCfg=SqlConfiguration [longQryWarnTimeout=1000, sqlQryHistSize=1000, sqlGlobalMemoryQuota=60%, sqlQueryMemoryQuota=0, sqlOffloadingEnabled=false, dfltQryTimeout=0]]
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: Daemon mode: off
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: OS: Linux 4.14.200-155.322.amzn2.x86_64 amd64
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: OS user: hadoop
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: PID: 14773
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: Language runtime: Java Platform API Specification ver. 1.8
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_272-b10 Amazon.com Inc. OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.272-b10
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: VM total memory: 2.0GB
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: Remote Management [restart: off, REST: off, JMX (remote: off)]
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: Logger: JavaLogger [quiet=true, config=null]
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: IGNITE_HOME=null
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: VM arguments: [-DEMR_CLUSTER_ID=j-3MH2DITFW5UJE, -DEMR_RELEASE_LABEL=emr-6.2.0, -DEMR_STEP_ID=s-FV02OVOM7RT4, -Xmx2048M, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70, -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled]
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: Configured caches [in 'sysMemPlc' dataRegion: ['ignite-sys-cache']]
21/03/25 17:32:26 WARN IgniteKernal: Please set system property '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to avoid possible problems in mixed environments.
21/03/25 17:32:26 WARN GridDiagnostic: Initial heap size is 236MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgnitePluginProcessor: Configured plugins:
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgnitePluginProcessor:   ^-- None
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgnitePluginProcessor: 
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO FailureProcessor: Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO TcpCommunicationSpi: Successfully bound communication NIO server to TCP port [port=47100, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, pairedConn=false]
21/03/25 17:32:26 WARN TcpCommunicationSpi: Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
21/03/25 17:32:26 WARN NoopCheckpointSpi: Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
21/03/25 17:32:26 WARN GridCollisionManager: Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
21/03/25 17:32:26 INFO IgniteKernal: Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
21/03/25 17:32:27 INFO PdsFoldersResolver: Consistent ID used for local node is [c2f73ab1-066c-4fc1-b1d2-2ebd6ca79311] according to persistence data storage folders
21/03/25 17:32:27 WARN IgniteH2Indexing: Serialization of Java objects in H2 was enabled.
21/03/25 17:32:27 INFO QueryMemoryManager: SQL query global quota was set to 1267571097. Current memory tracking parameters: [qryQuota=0, globalQuota=1267571097, offloadingEnabled=false]
21/03/25 17:32:27 INFO QueryMemoryManager: SQL query memory quota was set to 0. Current memory tracking parameters: [qryQuota=0, globalQuota=1267571097, offloadingEnabled=false]
21/03/25 17:32:27 INFO ClientListenerProcessor: Client connector processor has started on TCP port 10800
21/03/25 17:32:27 INFO GridRestProcessor: REST protocols do not start on client node. To start the protocols on client node set '-DIGNITE_REST_START_ON_CLIENT=true' system property.
21/03/25 17:32:28 INFO IgniteKernal: Non-loopback local IPs: 10.150.81.252, fe80:0:0:0:10bf:75ff:fe95:1e9%eth0
21/03/25 17:32:28 INFO IgniteKernal: Enabled local MACs: 12BF759501E9
21/03/25 17:32:28 INFO ClusterProcessor: Cluster ID and tag has been read from metastorage: null
21/03/25 17:32:28 INFO IgniteClusterImpl: Shutdown policy was updated [oldVal=null, newVal=null]
21/03/25 17:32:28 WARN TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder: Amazon client configuration is not set (will use default).
21/03/25 17:32:28 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 4, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 4743, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
21/03/25 17:32:28 ERROR IgniteKernal: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@f996445], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:280)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:986)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1931)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1284)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1771)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1150)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:670)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:611)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.getOrStart(Ignition.java:410)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson$.connectToIgniteClient(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala:158)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson$.loadPersonDataToIgniteCache(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala:63)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson$.connectToIgniteClusterAndLoadData(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala:37)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson$.main(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala:21)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson.main(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1024)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2019)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1996)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$1.body(ClientImpl.java:315)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:57)
21/03/25 17:32:28 ERROR IgniteKernal: Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1936)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1284)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1771)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1150)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:670)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:611)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.getOrStart(Ignition.java:410)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson$.connectToIgniteClient(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala:158)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson$.loadPersonDataToIgniteCache(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala:63)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson$.connectToIgniteClusterAndLoadData(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala:37)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson$.main(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala:21)
    at un.api.aws.client.IgniteCommunicatorPerson.main(IgniteCommunicatorPerson.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1024)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@f996445], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:280)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:986)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1931)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2019)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1996)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$1.body(ClientImpl.java:315)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:57)
21/03/25 17:32:28 INFO IgniteKernal:
```

Any suggestion to resolve the issue will be very much appreciated. I am using scala-version#2.12.12, spark-version#3.0.1 and OpenJDK-8 (for EC2 instance as well) for my EMR spark job.

Thanks,
Chandan

Comment: Any help or suggestion for this???

Comment: First of all Apache Ignite doesn't support spark 3. Only 2.3 and 2.4 are supported. So you are going to use not tested solution.

However, if you have the reproducer you can create a separate JIRA for the current issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Thanks  @Andrei Aleksandrov  for the update.